# Basic web service with authentication using php curl

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, curl

Need to consume some data from a web service that requires a username/password for access.

The following returns NULL

```
$service_url = 'https://example.com/2365139.json';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_response);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

When I hit https://example.com/2365139.json in a browser, it prompts for un/pw and when I enter them it displays the JSON, so the data is there but something I have written above isn't working.

Comment: Using curl_error just after curl_exec it says "Warning: curl_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: curl_error($curl_response); is used before curl_close();

Comment: try curl_error($curl) and tell us what it says

Comment: nothing is returned to the view when I do that

Comment: When I var_dump($curl_response) it returns 'bool(false)' and when I var_dump($curl) it returns 'resource(194) of type (curl)'

Comment: Cannot understand... if $curl_response === FALSE, then curl_error($curl) MUST give you an error message...

Comment: Could it be something to do with the web service itself not allowing this kind of access? I dont understand why it would be false but curl_error and curl_errno dont return anything at all...

Comment: May be... if it's not yours, ask the developer about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original code works fine, but because the resource is https it requires the following option;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

The caveat to using this is "This basically causes cURL to blindly accept any server certificate, without doing any verification as to which CA signed it, and whether or not that CA is trusted. If you’re at all concerned about the data you’re passing to or receiving from the server, you’ll want to enable this peer verification properly." - Taken from http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/